# How to change Celery's task name during runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, flower

I would like to name my tasks based on the arguments they are receiving. Below example is working, but the task name is empty(at least Flower is not displaying it). I would like to modify it so the task name is based on user name.

```
@app.task
def synchronize_users():
    users = crud_user.get_all_active_users()
    for user in users:
        synchronize_user.apply_async(warehouse)


@app.task(serializer='pickle')
def synchronize_user(user):
    user.synchronize()
```

Comment: This is likely an issue with your flower configuration.  But all celery classes have a name, even if one isn't specified explicitly using the `name` parameter on `app.task`.

Comment: changing a task name at run time is not recommended since celery keeps a list of registered tasks by name and rejects tasks that do not match that list.